# socket url on port 6001 showing not secure

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-16.04

I have GoDaddy SSL certificate and it is properly installed on my domain and my domain is working perfectly fine with https but when I open

https://.com:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js

Then it is showing not secure.

Earlier I had lets encrypt ssl certificate so yesterday I removed that and installed Godaddy SSl certificate but now facing this problem.

In my chrome, it is showing this https://prnt.sc/lvjv9w

Any suggestions please what could be the fix?

Answer (score 0):

using two ports for the same virtual host works alike this:

```
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:443

Listen 6001
NameVirtualHost *:6001

<VirtualHost *:443 *:6001>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yesterday I installed new GoDaddy certificate on it, live site working but only URL with port 6001 is not working

Comment: did you notice that certificate expired notice is only on URL with 6001, rest on complete website I can see new installed properly working certificate

Comment: @Jass `:8443` might work; it's one standard port besides `:443` - while the error message is explicit. also check in the browser address bar; there you can inspect the certificate. different vhosts can have different certificates. you might only have updated one of them, which is listening to `:443`.

Comment: I also called Godaddy and they verified that your certificate is installed properly and working online now

Comment: @Jass they might only have validated `:443` ...so what does it say, when clicking that one lock icon left to the address bar and then "Certificate"? I'd bet it says "Let's Encrypt Authority X3".

Comment: It is showing Verified by Godaddy, here you can see https://prnt.sc/lvjyzz

Comment: This is my current conf file so what changes I need to make? https://prnt.sc/lvk2ib

Comment: @Jass updated my answer accordingly. think the `Listen` directive could also be combined.

Comment: I disable virtual host , then changed file as per your suggestion. Then enable virtual host but still not working

Comment: @Jass why disable virtual host? make sure the `Listen` & `NameVirtualHost` are in the correct file (this might be the main `httpd.conf`). and reload the server after editing. the server's log should also show on which ports it is listening.

Comment: I am using ubuntu so don't have httpd.conf so I am changing in apache2.conf, In ports.conf, I have mentioned Listen 6001 but not sure about this NameVirtualHost *:443 and this <VirtualHost *:443 *:6001> I already done but have not worked so far, am I doing it in correct way?

Comment: @Jass add where the entries of the other host are. `sudo service apache2 reload` reloads the configuration. and when not sure, just keep backups of lines with a `#` (comment). there's also `apachectl configtest` which checks the validity of the syntax, not of the settings.

Comment: I've updated apache2 ports.conf to include `Listen 6001` and my virtualhost to `*:443 *:6001` but I'm still getting a valid SSL on https 443 and an invalid cert on https 6001 

Any other suggestions ?